# Laravel 5 and Sentinel 2

Tags: laravel-5.1, cartalyst-sentinel

I'm a complete starter using laravel 5.1. I was a PHP developer by 3 to 4 years and between those I was allways working with Java EE and I just came back to PHP environement and found a complete new list of frameworks.

After a little research, and using some surveys results, I found that Laravel is the ultimate one. Now I used Laragon to install it successfully and have my first fresh application running. I learning a little about how a route works and that's ok.

Now I need to use Sentinel 2.0 in order to apply the right roles/auth to my application and then add the socialize part.

So to do that, I need to know few things :

- Is there any way to "completely" get rid of the Auth component beside removing the controller Auth folder and the route in routes.php ?
- Is there any tutorial (as I can't find) telling how to REALLY include the sentinel means how to create a simple view with all what it needs (controller, vars, routes ....)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. For example, this is my code for API rest with JWT and Sentinel. You can seed your database with Sentinel:

**Create roles**

*Example EXA Role*

```
    $role = \Sentinel::getRoleRepository()->createModel()->create([
        'name' => 'Example',
        'slug' => 'EXA',
    ]);
    $role->permissions = [
        'servicio_dash' => true,
        'servicio_widget' => true,
    ];
    $role->save();
```

*User Role USR*

```
    $role = \Sentinel::getRoleRepository()->createModel()->create([
        'name' => 'User',
        'slug' => 'USR',
    ]);
    $role->permissions = [
        'servicio_dash' => true,
        'servicio_widget' =>false,
    ];
    $role->save();
```

**Create 50users and asignate EXA role(Using faker)**

```
    $usr_role = \Sentinel::findRoleBySlug('EXA');

    factory(App\User::class, 50)->make()->each(function ($u) use ($usr_role) {
        \Sentinel::registerAndActivate($u['attributes']);
    });
```

**Bonus Track: Factory example**

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
return [
    'email' => $faker->safeEmail,
    'password' => 'p4ssw0rd',
    'first_name' =>  $faker->firstName,
    'last_name' => $faker->lastName,
    'recycle' => false,
    'phone' => $faker->phoneNumber,
    'alt_email' => $faker->email
];
```

});

**Only one user**

```
$yo = factory(App\User::class)->make(['email' => 'jpaniorte@openmailbox.org']);
    \Sentinel::registerAndActivate($yo['attributes']);


    $jperez = User::where('email', 'jpaniorte@openmailbox.org')->firstOrFail();
    $epa_role->users()->attach($jperez);
```

**Authenticate Controller for API REST**

```
  public function authenticateCredentials(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    $user = \Sentinel::authenticate($credentials);
    return response()->json($user);
}
```

**Authenticate with token (use JWT) and sentinel**

```
 public function authenticate(Request $request)
{

    // grab credentials from the request
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    try {
        // attempt to verify the credentials and create a token for the user
        if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
    }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }
    // all good so return the token
    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}
```

*Note: For this, you need configure JWT options with custom Auth provider, you can find this [here](https://gist.github.com/iolson/8a4c6d689a334f6de48e)*

**In any controller**

```
public function hasPermission($type)
{
    //$sentinel = \Sentinel::findById(\JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()->id); //->this is for a token

    $sentinel = \Sentinel::findById(1); //if you now the id


    if($sentinel->hasAccess([$type]))
        return response()->json(true, 200);
    //yout custom handle for noAccess here
}
```